# How can I add a bounty to a question?

Tags: support, bounties

I can't seem to add a bounty to one of my questions on SO - what are the rules governing adding bounties?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q="bounty"+[faq]

Comment: @PatrickHofman do not edit the banner out as long as it's still closed! It is **VERY VERY** confusing.

Comment: @PatrickHofman done, just keep that in mind for the future. (And others doing same wrong edits)

Answer (score 9):

The question is too new to add a bounty - it has to be at least 48 hours old.

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

> If, **after two days**, you still don't have an answer you like, you can offer a bounty. Slice off a bit of your own hard-earned reputation -- anywhere from 50 to 500 -- and attach it to the question as a bounty. We'll even throw in 50 reputation to sweeten the deal. The bountied question will appear with a special icon in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the home page Featured tab.